# Where does Alfresco store the documents information in its database?

Tags: database, alfresco

I'm working on an app that connects to alfresco database.
and I was looking in the tables for the table that contains documents information, and I couldn't find it. I found the table of tasks and other tables.
can anybody help me here?

Comment: As I've written in my answer to your question yesterday, the Alfresco database is highly normalized. There is no single table to hold all information about a node. Please [edit] your question and include what specific information you want to read. Then I will be able to help you write the SQL.

Comment: You should not be querying the Alfresco database directly. The schema is not public and could change without notice. It is strongly preferable to go through the public RESTful API.

Comment: @JeffPotts We have many use cases that can only be solved by working directly on the DB, especially unusual maintenance tasks. The REST API can be used for client interaction but to find and fix problems, knowledge of the DB structure is very helpful.

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to be able to store documents from my web app into alfresco database, so you can give any information that can help, or any documentation about the subject. thank you!

Comment: Don't do this. Storing a document is a very complex operation which must be left to Alfresco. Why do you want to do this directly in the DB?

Comment: No note directly in DB, I want to use the REST API to communicate with Alfresco repository, just that

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm willing to use API REST

Comment: @LutzHorn, my statement still stands. You shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The two most important tables, IMHO, are `alf_node` and `alf_node_properties`. Note, for each node you create you will get a single row in the former, and multiple rows in the latter, depending on the number of metadata associated with your node.

This is because metadata are stored as rows in `alf_node_properties` with `qname_id` column holding the information about metadata type.

Answer (score 0):

All files that are stored in Alfresco are stored in what is referred to as the repository. The repository is a logical entity that consists of three important parts:

1. The physical content files that are uploaded (in `{Alfresco_install_dir}/alf_data/contentstore`)
2. The index files created when indexing the uploaded file so it is
   searchable
3. The metadata/properties for the file, which are stored in a
   relational database management system (RDBMS).

For more details check [Repository concepts](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-repository-concepts.html)

Comment: Only 3. is relevant to the question which is about how the tables are organized. You don't answer this.